# Is there a way to name lists using variables?

Tags: java

Using Java I am importing a CSV file which contains a list of topic types and questions. I have produced a list of the topics (in my test I have 10 topics and 29 questions).

I would like to create a series of lists for each topic, but instead of typing the list names directly into the source code which I currently have I would like to use names generated from values in the CSV file.

```
//current code (ExamQuestion is a custom class)
List<ExamQuestion> hardwareList = new ArrayList<>();

//desired code (in real version variable value would come from CSV file)
String listName = "hardwareList";
List<ExamQuestion> listName = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant name the variable by using other's variable String value, but may be for your purpouse would be usefull using HashMap

```
 List<ExamQuestion> listName = new ArrayList<>();
 Map<String, List<ExamQuestion>> map = new HashMap<>();
 map.put("name", new ArrayList<>());
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, it is not possible to use `String`s as variable names. What you can do, however, is create a `Map<String, List<ExampleQuestion>>` and store to a `List<...>` to a given `String` (its "name").

Take a look at [@Ludov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57232029/4216641) tor a sketch implementation utilizing `HashMap<...>`.